How to change DataGridViewCheckBox value or checked status from Form_Load event or any other method without having to click?
I am trying to get data from database and check / uncheck the DataGridViewCheckbox depending on some criteria
Here is my code
Form Load :
private void TestForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FillGrid();
    GetData();
}

FillGrid Method :
private void FillGrid()
{
    gvItems.DataSource = null;
    gvItems.Rows.Clear();
    gvItems.Columns.Clear();

    if (gvItems.Columns.Contains("chkSelect") == false)
    {
        DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn bcol = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
        bcol.HeaderText = "Select";
        bcol.DisplayIndex = 0;
        bcol.Name = "chkSelect";
        bcol.Width = 80;
        gvItems.Columns.Add(bcol);
    }

    using (DataTable dtBrand = c.GetDataTable("Select brandId, brandCode, brandDesc From BrandMaster"))
    {
        gvItems.DataSource = dtBrand;
        gvItems.Columns["brandId"].Visible = false;
        gvItems.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;

        gvItems.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Tahoma", 10F, FontStyle.Bold);

        gvItems.Columns["brandCode"].Width = 100;
        gvItems.Columns["brandCode"].HeaderText = "Code";
        gvItems.Columns["brandCode"].ReadOnly = true;

        gvItems.Columns["brandDesc"].Width = 200;
        gvItems.Columns["brandDesc"].HeaderText = "Brand Desc";
        gvItems.Columns["brandDesc"].ReadOnly = true;

        gvItems.RowHeadersVisible = false;
    }
}

GetData Method :
private void GetData()
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gvItems.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells["brandId"].Value.ToString() == "2")
        {
            gvItems.Rows[1].Cells[0].Value = true;
        }
    }
}

I have tried with SetValue, it does not work either

Are you sure that the code line gets hit? Try setting a breakpoint on that line.

I tried the different solutions suggested here, and it did not work. Finally i used a timer and after GetData() method is called, I enabled the timer and in timer tick event i used the same code to check the checkboxes and it worked. Weird behavior but finally I can go further.

That's probably because the GridView is updated asynchron so calling your code directly has not yet updated the GridView. When using a timer you give the GridView time to update first.

You should set the checkbox value for the specific row you're iterating over. Here's how you can modify the GetData method:
private void GetData()
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gvItems.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells["brandId"].Value.ToString() == "2")
        {
            row.Cells["chkSelect"].Value = true; // Check the checkbox in the current row
        }
        else
        {
            row.Cells["chkSelect"].Value = false; // Uncheck the checkbox if the condition is not met
        }
    }
}


Whenever possible, work with the DataTable then the DataGridView to, in this case toggle a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn.
Below, mocked data is used for the data and a column is added to the DataTable to represent the DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn.
Processing of the checkbox column is done dependent on the DataColumn value for CountryCode.
public class MockedDataOperation
{
    /// <summary>
    /// In place of database operation
    /// </summary>
    public static DataTable GetDataFromDatabase()
    {

        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns["Id"].ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden;
        dt.Columns["Id"].AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
        dt.Columns["Id"].AutoIncrement = true;
        dt.Columns.Add("FirstName", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("LastName", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("CountryCode", typeof(string));

        dt.Rows.Add(null, "Jose", "Fernandez", "2");
        dt.Rows.Add(null, "Miguel", "Lopez", "1");
        dt.Rows.Add(null, "Angel", "Perez", "2");
        dt.Rows.Add(null, "Ben", "Perez", "2");
        
        SetupForCheckBox(dt);

        return dt;

    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Add column to represent a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
    /// Set the checkbox value based on the CountryCode
    /// </summary>
    private static void SetupForCheckBox(DataTable dt, bool process = false)
    {
        // Add column for checkbox
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn()
        {
            ColumnName = "Process",
            DataType = typeof(bool),
            DefaultValue = false
        });

        // move checkbox column to the first position
        dt.Columns["Process"]!.SetOrdinal(0);

        if (!process) return;
        for (int index = 0; index < dt.Rows.Count; index++)
        {
            if (dt.Rows[index].Field<string>("CountryCode") == "2")
            {
                dt.Rows[index].SetField("Process", true);
            }
        }

    }
}

Form code, a DataGridView and two buttons.
public partial class CheckboxForm : Form
{
    public CheckboxForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dataGridView1.DataSource = MockedDataOperation.GetDataFromDatabase();

        dataGridView1.Columns["Process"].Width = 50;
        dataGridView1.Columns["Process"].HeaderText ="";
    }

    // toggle process column dependent on CountryCode
    private void ChangeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;
        for (int index = 0; index < dt.Rows.Count; index++)
        {
            if (dt.Rows[index].Field<string>("CountryCode") == "2")
            {
                dt.Rows[index].SetField("Process", true);
            }
            else
            {
                dt.Rows[index].SetField("Process", false);
            }
        }
    }
    // access current row data
    private void CurrentButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewRow currentRow = dataGridView1.CurrentRow;

        if (currentRow != null)
        {
            DataRow row = ((DataRowView)currentRow.DataBoundItem).Row;
        }
    }

}

